# Override Parent POM Spring version

Tags: spring, maven

In a Package with several java Projects there is a Common Prj that makes references to a Parent POM. 
This Parent POM is in a Central Nexus Repository.
Spring 3.x is specified in the Parent POM.

I want use Spring 4.x locally, just for test this version.

I have used property in Local POM with Spring.version 4.x
but Parent override this one with 3.x

How can I used force in my Local POM use spring 4.x?

SpringVersion.getVersion() prints :  3.0.1.RELEASE

Comment: can you add the POM and its Parent so we can see how the dependencies are managed? You may be able to just override a property. Else you could just define a dependencyManagement node and set the Spring framework BOM

Comment: Fixed putting in "dependencyManagement"